# how to get facebook page conversations through Restfb ?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I working on an application that manages a facebook page. I have to load the private conversations on this page. I am using restfb graph api for this purpose. I tried some examples but they are not working. Below is code that i am trying for your reference.

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);

for(List<Conversation> conversationPage : conversations) {
  for(Conversation conversation : conversationPage) {
    System.out.println(conversation);
    System.out.println(conversation.getUnreadCount());

    Message lastMessage = null;
    for (Message message : conversation.getMessages())
    {
      System.out.println("Message text = " + message.getMessage());
      System.out.println("Message unread = " + message.getUnread());
      System.out.println("Message from = " + message.getFrom().getName());
      System.out.println("Message to = " + message.getTo().get(0).getName());
      System.out.println("Message unseen = " + message.getUnseen());
      lastMessage = message;
    }
  }
}
```

but it is giving me 0 message count at

> System.out.println(conversation.getUnreadCount());

While i have manage unread messages at my page. I require your help to resolve this issue. Please advice.

Comment: What kind of access token are you using for your API call, and which permissions does it include?

Comment: Thanks for replying..
I am using permanent page access token, how can i check the permissions for access token of a page ?

Comment: Copy&paste it into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: these are the scopes assigned to the token. I guess these scopes defines the access ? 

**user_birthday, 
user_religion_politics, 
user_relationships, 
user_relationship_details, 
user_hometown, 
user_location, 
user_likes, 
user_managed_groups, 
user_photos, 
user_friends, 
user_about_me, 
user_status, 
user_posts, 
read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, 
read_insights, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions**

Comment: That should be ok. Maybe the messages are not unread (any more), can you check what the overall count is? Also, try your request in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and see what result you get there.

Comment: I have checked the count. It is giving me correct count of the conversations i.e 3. 
Here is the output for your reference.

Comment: "data": [ { "updated_time": "2016-01-19T10:16:38+0000", "link": "/testAccount/manager/messages/=mid.xxasd%3&folder=inbox", "id": "t_mid.1453184898762:mmx" }, 

{ "updated_time": "2016-01-19T10:06:13+0000", "link": "/testAccount/manager/messages/?mercurythreadid=user%3Aadsasd53s448&threadid=mid‌​.sdasdxxas%3&folder=inbox", "id": "t_mid.1453184898762:ssx" }, 

{ "updated_time": "2016-01-19T07:00:15+0000", "link": "/testAccount/manager/messages/ mid.1453184898762%3&folder=inbox", "id": "t_mid.1453184898762:asdadadsad" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), for your help. I got the answer by debugging facebook graph api. here is the code which i have used.

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);
     for(List<Conversation> conversationPage : conversations) {
        for(Conversation conversation : conversationPage) {
          String id = conversation.getId();
          Connection<Message> messages = facebookClient.fetchConnection(id + "/messages", Message.class, Parameter.with("fields", "message,created_time,from,id"));
        }
     }
```